# PHP - Using a Double colon with a class varible

Tags: php, class, static, scope-resolution

I'm trying to call a static function with a varible name from a class.

The desired outcome:

```
class Controller extends Controller {
    public $model = 'ModelName';
    public function index() {
        $woot = $this->model::find('');
        var_dump($woot);
    }
}
```

This works:

```
$class = 'ClassName';
$object = $class::find($parameters);
```

This works too:

```
$class = new Model();
$object = $class::find($params);
```

I am trying to define the new class name inside the current class, and call find as a static function from the current model.
Any ideas how it's possible, without creating a new object, using `__set`, or declaring a local variable in the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that actually. Within a class instance you cannot use `$this->var` to reference another class. You can, however, assign it to another local variable and have that work

```
public function index() {
    $var = $this->model;
    $woot = $var::find('');
    var_dump($woot);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with *Machavity*'s method, but you can use `call_user_func()` or `call_user_func_array()`:

```
public function index() {
    $woot = call_user_func_array(array($this->model, 'find'), array(''));
}
```